# salto de linea en powershell

Tags: powershell

hola soy nueva en cuanto a programacion, pero estoy usando PowerShell, y quiero hacer un script donde se muestren los permisos de un usuario.

Ya lo logré, solo que me muestra todos los permisos y no se alcanzan a ver todos:

```
Function Get-UserPermission
{
  param(
  [string]$Identity)

  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName,memberof  -SearchBase 
  "OU=Reynosa,OU=HMD,OU=AMR,OU=MAC,DC=emrsn,DC=org" |
  where {$_.samAccountName -match $Identity} | format-table DisplayName, Memberof 
}
```

> PS C:> Get-UserPermission -Identity karina
>
> DisplayName                    Memberof
>
> -----------                    --------                                                                                                      Garcia, Karina                 {CN=HM REY HALLFAMEDASH,OU=HM REY File
>   Shares,OU=Groups,OU=Reynosa,OU=HMD,OU=AMR,OU=MAC,DC=emrsn,DC=org, C...
>   Gaspar, Karina [COMRES/HM/REY] {CN=EC MDM Global
>   VelocityEHS,OU=Groups,OU=STL,OU=Corporate,OU=AMR,OU=Corporate,DC=emrsn,DC=org,
>   CN=DL All...

Pero no puedo ver todos los permisos.

Como puedo dar un salto x cada `,` ??

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es separar la información y luego expandir los valores de **Memberof**:

```
Function Get-UserPermission
{
  param(
  [string]$Identity)

  Write-host "Usuario: " -NoNewline 
  Write-host $Identity
  Write-host "-------------"
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName,memberof  -SearchBase 
  "OU=Reynosa,OU=HMD,OU=AMR,OU=MAC,DC=emrsn,DC=org" |
  where {$_.samAccountName -match $Identity} | 
  select Memberof -ExpandProperty Memberof | Format-Table

}
```

El resultado sería algo así:

```
Usuario: vsilva
-------------
CN=Admins RODC,OU=Grupos,OU=empresa,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=VMM_Admins,OU=SCVMM Grupos,OU=SCVMM,OU=SystemCenter,OU=empresa,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=Admins_Sharepoint,OU=Permisos Sharepoint,OU=empresa,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=Administradores de empresa,OU=Grupos,OU=empresa,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=Administradores de organización,CN=Users,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=Usuarios de escritorio remoto,CN=Builtin,DC=dominio,DC=local
CN=Organization Management,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=dominio,DC=local
```

Entiendo que hay mejores formas, pero creo que para resolver el problema con ese pequeño cambio es más que suficiente.